# JfreeChart XYPlot: Remove 0 on domain axis

Tags: jfreechart

Is there a way to remove the 0 in domain axis, so that the values of x = 0 are drawn at x = 1?
I don't want to remove all the values at x = 0, I just want to "push" them one unit to the right and remove the 0-mark.

One example:

Series1: (-2, 1), (-1, 2), (0, 2), (2, 5) should become (-2, 1), (-1, 2), (1, 2), (3, 5)

And the domain axis should alter like this:

-|----|----|----|----|----|-    should become  -|----|----|----|-

-2_-1_  0_  1__  2_  3_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**-2_ -1__1 _2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an XYPlot

```java
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.getDomainAxis().setRange(min, max);
```

or

```java
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.setLowerBound(1);
```

If you only know the minimum value

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't mention there are negative values as well. I edit the question.